# MS Word - Define style to mark index item

Tags: ms-word

Is there a way to create a Word Style that also marks the text as an index item?

IOW, instead of highlighting a phrase, selecting the References Tab and choosing Mark Entry, I'd like to give the text a Style and that also marks it as an index entry.

All text having that style will show up in the generated index.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't possible.

If you read [this article about creating index entries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-index-and-update-an-index-cc502c71-a605-41fd-9a02-cda9d14bf073) you may understand why.